# Reading duplicated objects on files C++

Tags: c++, file, oop, fstream, archive

I'm having some trouble with creating a file system to my program in C++. Well, I am creating a new student, and, if he is the last object that I'm creating before saving the files and closing the program, it gets duplicated. For example, two objects: Daniel, **Paul**. It shows just the last one duplicated: Daniel, **Paul**, **Paul** - in the file.txt.

Here is some code of mine:

FILE READING:

```
ifstream file;
file.open("file.txt");

while (1)
{
Student *p = new Student();
    if (file.eof() || file.bad() || file.fail())
    {
        break;
    }

    getline(file, ALLTHESTRINGVARIABLES);
    p->STRINGVARIABLES = ALLTHESTRINGVARIABLES;

    file >> ANOTHERVARIABLES;
    p->NOTSTRINGVARIABLES = ANOTHERVARIABLES;

    students.push_back(p);
}
file.close();
```

FILE WRITING:

```
   fstream file;
   file.open("file.txt", ios::out | ios::trunc);
      for(unsigned int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++){
         file << students[i]->VARIABLEEXAMPLE << endl;
      }
   file.close();
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use `new`. Just make it `Student p;` and make it `std::vector<Student> students;` to avoid manual memory management.

Comment: Show the `Student` and an example of `file.txt`. Make a  [mcve].

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo yo're probably right but as the student container contains pointers we need an allocation (unique_ptr or shared_ptr perhaps?). There is no way to tell without the complete code and the actual use case. That is, is there a good reason to use a container of pointers? We simlpy can't tell from what we are given :(

Comment: Ok, but why not make the student container like I suggested? Is dynamic dispatch being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eof(), bad(), fail() will only return true after a try to read some bytes from the file without success. So, put the if verification after the getline().

And just make the new instance of the Student after this if to avoid a memory leak.

Like that:

```
while (1)
{
    getline(file, ALLTHESTRINGVARIABLES);
    if (file.eof() || file.bad() || file.fail())
        break;

    Student *p = new Student();
    p->STRINGVARIABLES = ALLTHESTRINGVARIABLES;

    file >> ANOTHERVARIABLES;
    p->NOTSTRINGVARIABLES = ANOTHERVARIABLES;

    students.push_back(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`eof()` will not return `true` until you've actually tried to read beyond the end of the file which is why you see the last line duplicated. The `getline` will fail and `ALLTHESTRINGVARIABLES` will contain the values from the latest successful read. You should instead check if the extraction actually succeeded before storing a new `Student`.

Since you mix unformatted and formatted input, you should also remove the newline (or whatever character you use to separate the records) from the stream.

Change the loop to:

```
if (std::ifstream file("file.txt"); file)
{
    while (std::getline(file, ALLTHESTRINGVARIABLES) >> ANOTHERVARIABLES)
    {
        // remove the newline or whatever whitespace char you use as record separator
        file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        Student *p = new Student;
        p->STRINGVARIABLES = ALLTHESTRINGVARIABLES;
        p->NOTSTRINGVARIABLES = ANOTHERVARIABLES;
        students.push_back(p);
    }
}
```

I also suggest that you don't store pointers (unless you use dynamic dispatch) but instead store the actual `Student` objects in a `std::vector<Student>`. If dynamic dispatch is used, then store `std::unique_ptr<Student>` in the `vector`.

Comment: Ted, thank you for the help! Derzu, the programmer who earlier replied received the check mark because it also was a solution.

Comment: @DanielCassianoChaves You're welcome! Just be aware that if `file >> ANOTHERVARIABLES;` fails when using the other answer, you'll add a broken `Student` to the `vector`. Also, I can't see how it can work without removing the record separator.